# Finding Real Time Debug Tool for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have seen a **video** showing a real time debugging tool for **vs2012**.
It allows you to *code* and *debug* at the same time !
In the video, they implemented "**Quick Sort**", by editing "*conditions for if statement*" and 
"*the index of array*".
**Hover your mouse over a variable, the value will be evaluate on sight**.
Then, the programmer can discover whether the condition in algorithm is smaller or bigger.

Unfortunately, I forgot its link. It something like '**Light Table**', which enable you to see the result of code by hovering your mouse onto the variable name.

It's really cool. Where is it ? Any clues will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like [this](http://ermau.com/making-instant-csharp-viable-visualization/) or [this](http://www.chris-granger.com/2012/04/12/light-table---a-new-ide-concept/)?
They're both inspired by Bret Victor's great talk [Inventing on Principle](https://vimeo.com/36579366)

Comment: Exactly, what i missed. Interestingly, "Vizualization" is misspelled.That's why I can't find it on hacknews search engine.